# Will Autofac support IWebHostBuilder API in netcore 3+?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting

It looks like Autofac only supports the generic hosting API, `IHostBuilder`. I wonder if the old asp netcore 2.x documentation is still relevant to asp netcore 3 applications.

Also, I found https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore has not been updated for a long time, so I guess Autofac has no intention to support `IWebHostBuilder` in the future...

Do we have any guideline about how to set up Autofac in AspNetCore 3.x using the `IWebHostBuilder` API?

I read about [this][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980827/service-fabric-aspnet-core-3-1-autofac-webhostbuilder] post, and it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 3.x they changed how dependency injection integrates and, no, the version 2.x documentation no longer applies - either in the Autofac case or in the ASP.NET case. ASP.NET Core intentionally shifted to the generic hosting model, where the web host is a layer on top of that.

It's not that Autofac "has no intention of supporting `IWebHostBuilder`", it's that *that's not an option* in ASP.NET Core 3. It changed at the framework level; that's not how you integrate with ASP.NET Core anymore. You don't attach the DI factory to the web host anymore, you attach it to the outer generic host.

You *do* register things in your `Startup` class just like in ASP.NET Core 2.

[The docs you linked to](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting) explain all of that and show examples. You can also [see in the Microsoft ASP.NET Core 2 to 3 migration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#hostbuilder-replaces-webhostbuilder) that `HostBuilder` replaces `WebHostBuilder`; and that `WebHostBuilder`, while it might still exist, is being deprecated and you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create constructor parameters have `IWebHostEnvironment` on the Startup class and asp.net core will auto inject `IWebHostEnvironment`.
Register `IWebHostBuilder` as instance on the `ConfigureContainer`.

See the below code.

```
public class Startup
{     
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    // Auto injection IWebHostEnvironment
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {        
        _environment = environment;
    }
     
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // Autofac ID
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Register your own things directly with Autofac, like:
        builder.Register<SampleClass>();
        
        // Register your IWebHostEnvironment
        builder.RegisterInstance(_environment);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class SampleClass
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    // If you register IWebHostEnvironment on the Startup, IWebHostEnvironment will auto inject.
    public SampleClass(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }
}
```

When you resolve the `SampleClass`, you can see the `IWebHostEnvironment` is auto injected to constructor.