# How to use Service Fabric service with AspNet Core WebApi and Autofac and run TestServer

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, service-fabric-stateless, testserver

I can't figure out how to use an AspNet Core 3.1 Web Api with Service Fabric and Autofac, and also how to have it ready for a TestServer to run for integration/functional testing.

The documentation is very incomplete.

Autofac documentation shows how to modify `Program.cs` to build autofac container, but it does not mention anything about the Startup.cs class that all the web api have:
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/servicefabric.html

Also the only example that Autofac has for service fabric is not a web api: https://github.com/autofac/Examples/tree/master/src/ServiceFabricDemo

There are other questions without valid answers:
[Service Fabric AspNet Core 3.1 Autofac WebHostBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980827/service-fabric-aspnet-core-3-1-autofac-webhostbuilder)

Does anybody have any example on how to achieve this?

I can achieve the following (please see [my GitHub repository with the sample](https://github.com/diegosasw/issue-aspnetcore-servicefabric-autofac-testserver/tree/feature/microsoft_dependency_injection))

- Service fabric with stateless AspNet Core WebApi project (dotnet core 3.1)
- Using Microsoft Dependency Injection to register services
- Using TestServer to run integration tests on the http endpoint, and able to overwrite dependency injection registrations in a clean way **without having to create another Startup class**

I want the exact same, but using Autofac as DI container.

---

UPDATE 1:
I can't add Autofac to a `WebHostBuilder` and the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` must be void as per AspNet Core 3.1+, so this is where I'm stuck. How to replace MS Dependency Injection in my sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event after the bounty there is not an answer to this. Maybe it's not possible as service fabric requires WebHost and not generic host.

In any case, I managed to have it working with older versions. Here's my repository where I show a sample on how to run AspNetCore2.1 with DotNetCore2.1 (LTS) and Autofac under Service Fabric. I use the webhost builder, not the generic one.

https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/training/sasw-aspnetcore-testing/-/tree/master/aspnetcore2_1_autofac_servicefabric

Still, it'd be nice to eventually have a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have NO idea if this works for the TestServer. It does however work fine with during ordinary hosting.

The exact thing you are looking for would be this line: `services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IServiceProviderFactory<ContainerBuilder>>(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory(null)));`

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(
            serviceContext => new KestrelCommunicationListener(
                serviceContext,
                (url, listener) =>
                    {
                        return WebHost
                            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
                            .ConfigureServices(services =>
                            {
                                services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IServiceProviderFactory<ContainerBuilder>>(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory(null)));
                                services.AddSingleton(serviceContext)
                            })
                            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl | ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseReverseProxyIntegration)
                            .UseStartup<TStartupType>()
                            .Build();
                    }))
    };
}
```

Hope it helps, it took me quite a while to arrive at this solution.